# Error when setting variable in an Excel VBA Application

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I've created a working macro that runs linear regression statistical analysis on a data set.  The final piece is to have a variable service level (# between 0 and 100) that the user can enter, then that value will be used in the VBA code.

Here's the working code with a standard service level set at 90:

```
' Run Regression Application
Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A" & LastRow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$" & LastRow), False, True, 90, ActiveSheet.Range("$D:$BK") _
        , True, True, True, True, , False
```

When I added ServiceLevel as a var:

```
' Run Regression Application
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ServiceLevel As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ServiceLevel = Range("AA4").Value
     Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A" & LastRow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$" & LastRow), False, True, ServiceLevel, ActiveSheet.Range("$D:$BK") _
        , True, True, True, True, , False
```

And I get this error:
Regression - Confidence must be a number between 0 and 100

Comment: First guess would be that the value in AA4 is not between 0 and 100.

Comment: I ran a msgbox to output ServiceLevel, the output was 95.

Comment: `Add Debug.Print ServiceLevel` before `Application.Run` - what is the output in the Immediate Window? Also, what `Worksheet` is `Range("AA4")` on? You should fully qualify it, otherwise `ActiveSheet` is implied, which might not be the sheet you expect.

Comment: Nothing changed by adding Debug.Print ServiceLevel.  There is only 1 worksheet, so it does not need to be qualified in this case.

Comment: And if you hit Ctrl+G within the VB editor to bring up the Immediate Window, the output is 95? I cannot replicate your error.

Comment: Yes.  This makes no sense.

Comment: Ben, so here's a weird point.  When I run Debug.Print in it's own Sub, I get 95 in the Immediate Window; however, if Debug.Print is placed before Application.Run, the Immediate Window is blank.  I tried "0" & ServiceLevel in Application.Run line of code and it ran the regression at 0 confidence level.  So ServiceLevel variable is not being recognized.  Hopefully this will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Resolved.  Qualified the sheet and it worked.